# WPF ListView: Attaching a double-click (on an item) event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following `ListView`:

```
<ListView Name="TrackListView">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Title" Width="100" 
                            HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource BlueHeader}" 
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>

            <GridViewColumn Header="Artist" Width="100"  
                            HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource BlueHeader}"  
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Album.Artist.Name}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

How can I attach an event to every bound item that will fire on double-clicking the item?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Found the solution from here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/3d0eaa54-09a9-4c51-8677-8e90577e7bac/

---

XAML:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="itemstyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="HandleDoubleClick" />
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<ListView Name="TrackListView" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource itemstyle}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Title" Width="100" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource BlueHeader}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Artist" Width="100" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource BlueHeader}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Album.Artist.Name}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

C#:

```cs
protected void HandleDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var track = ((ListViewItem) sender).Content as Track; //Casting back to the binded Track
}
```

Comment: If you don't need to re-use the style, you can put it directly into the <ListView.Resources/> section and remove the x:Key.

Comment: This worked for me, too.  Thanks!
BTW, you will probably want to stop the bubbling of the doubleClick event within your handler by setting:
   e.Handled = true;

Comment: I have a problem with this. That is, I use x:Key-less styles in the window to style all the UI elements, including the ListViews used in a custom control on that window. Putting this event-handler in the custom control's xaml disables the style applied in the window.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there another way to do this that doesn't violate MVVM?

Comment: Yes, in place of retrieving the selected item into the Content property of the sender parameter of the event, you can bind the SelectedItem of the listview and take this value into the handler of the double click event.

Comment: As a warning: using an `EventSetter` can lead to memory leaks if its handler's target lives longer than the `ListViewItem`.  I spent the last few days debugging a serious memory leak (20mb at a time), only to find out that `ListViewItem`s and their associated memory were being leaked through an `EventSetter`.

Comment: @Dave (and those who upvoted his comment): See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35735737/3549027) to [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4360998/3549027) for a more MVVM-y way of achieving this (short answer, turn the code into an attached behavior).

Answer (score 86):

No memory leaks *(no need to unsubscribe each item)*, works fine:

XAML:

```
<ListView MouseDoubleClick="ListView_MouseDoubleClick" ItemsSource="{Binding TrackCollection}" />
```

C#:

```
    void ListView_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = ((FrameworkElement) e.OriginalSource).DataContext as Track;
        if (item != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Item's Double Click handled!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Excellent, no more need to worry about memory leaks, and frankly it's just a hell of a lot cleaner.

Comment: This is not enough if your list contains a complex object. You need to use a visual tree helper to find the parent ListViewItem and from there you can take the datacontext

Comment: Very nice and helpful. In my case I have the additional select button that does the select action. So I used the double click as follows:
'MouseDoubleClick="SelectBtn_Click"'
'private void SelectBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
}'

Comment: This is why you always scroll past the accepted answer. Just in case...

Comment: Don't think this works if you double click on the scrollbar.

Answer (score 10):

My solution was based on [@epox_sub's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4888542/492) which you should look at for  where to put the Event Handler in the XAML. The code-behind didn't work for me because my `ListViewItems` are complex objects. [@sipwiz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/728243/492) was a great hint for where to look...

```
void ListView_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var item = ListView.SelectedItem as Track;
    if (item != null)
    {
      MessageBox.Show(item + " Double Click handled!");
    }
}
```

The bonus with this is you get the `SelectedItem`'s DataContext binding (`Track` in this case). Selected Item works because the first click of the double-click selects it.

Comment: This works great but, unfortunately, the double click event is also fired when the user double clicks empty space in the listview and, since the SelectedItem is not cleared when the user clicks on empty space, the event is executed on the previously selected item.

Answer (score 10):

Using MVVM is possible if you install the Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviours.WPF package.

Once you have installed the package then you can reference it in your XAML like so:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
```

You can then add the following to your ListView, which binds a command in your View Model to the Mouse Double Click event.

```
<ListView 
    x:Name="ListView" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedTrack}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTrack}" >
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction 
                Command="{Binding SelectTrackCommand}"
                CommandParameter={Binding ElementName=ListView, Path=SelectedItems}/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        ...........
        ...........
</ListView>
```

The `Command` attribute should bind to a Command implementation in your ViewModel.  For example:

```
private CommandHandler<IList> _SelectTrackCommand;
public CommandHandler<IList> SelectTrackCommand => _SelectTrackCommand ?? (_SelectTrackCommand = new CommandHandler<IList>(items =>
            {
                SelectionChanged(items);
            }));
```

Where the SelectionChanged method above is doing something with the ListView items.

NOTE: that the ListView items are passed in using the `CommandParameter` in XAML.  This is optional but can be useful if you want to operate on the SelectedItems or SelectedItem from within your Command and are not binding these elsewhere in your ViewModel.

Answer (score 5):

For those interested in mostly maintaining the MVVM pattern, I used [Andreas Grech's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/728248/4254572) to make a work-around.

> **Basic flow:**
>
> User double-clicks item -> Event handler in code behind -> ICommand in
>   view model

ProjectView.xaml:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Key="listViewDoubleClick">
        <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="ListViewItem_MouseDoubleClick"/>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

...

<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}" 
          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource listViewDoubleClick}"/>
```

ProjectView.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class ProjectView : UserControl
{
    public ProjectView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ListViewItem_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ((ProjectViewModel)DataContext)
            .ProjectClick.Execute(((ListViewItem)sender).Content);
    }
}
```

ProjectViewModel.cs:

```
public class ProjectViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Project> Projects { get; set; } = 
               new ObservableCollection<Project>();

    public ProjectViewModel()
    {
        //Add items to Projects
    }

    public ICommand ProjectClick
    {
        get { return new DelegateCommand(new Action<object>(OpenProjectInfo)); }
    }

    private void OpenProjectInfo(object _project)
    {
        ProjectDetailView project = new ProjectDetailView((Project)_project);
        project.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

DelegateCommand.cs can be found [here](http://wpftutorial.net/DelegateCommand.html).

In my instance, I have a collection of `Project` objects that populate the `ListView`. These objects contain more properties than are shown in the list, and I open a `ProjectDetailView` (a WPF `Window`) to display them.

The `sender` object of the event handler is the selected `ListViewItem`. Subsequently, the `Project` that I want access to is contained within the `Content` property.

Answer (score 2):

Building on [epox_spb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4888542/747369), I added in a check to avoid errors when double clicking in the GridViewColumn headers.

```cs
void ListView_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var dataContext = ((FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource).DataContext;
    if (dataContext is Track)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Item's Double Click handled!");
    }
}
```

Comment: very cool - works with PowerShell- `$myListView.Add_MouseDoubleClick({ Param($sender, $ev); $e = [System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs]$ev; $itemData = ([System.Windows.FrameworkElement]$e.OriginalSource).DataContext  }); if ($item -ne $null) { Write-Host $itemData; } })` --- Casting is not required but helps in ISE to get completion

Answer (score 1):

In your example are you trying to catch when an item in your ListView is selected or when a column header is clicked on? If it's the former you would add a SelectionChanged handler.

```
<ListView Name="TrackListView" SelectionChanged="MySelectionChanged">
```

If it's the latter you would have to use some combination of MouseLeftButtonUp or MouseLeftButtonDown events on the GridViewColumn items to detect a double click and take appropriate action. Alternatively you could handle the events on the GridView and work out from there which column header was under the mouse.

Comment: I wanted an event on the bounded items, not the headers

Comment: That's a new one for me. Thanks for putting up your answer (and I'll remove the no DoubleClick event statement from mine).

Answer (score 1):

if you are populating your `Listview` through a 
`ObservableCollection<ItemClass> Items` class , 
and non of the answer above works for you "as what happen to me" , then use :

```
private void ListView_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var item = ((FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource).DataContext as ItemClass; //<< your class name here

    if (item != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(item.UserName + " : item Double Click handled!");
    }
}
```

of course **`ItemClass`** would be your **setter/getter** class name