# Get the item doubleclick event of listview

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

What do I need to do in order to reference the double click event for a listview control?

Comment: probably you want to bind to double click event of item?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I'm using something like this to only trigger on ListViewItem double-click and not for example when you double-click on the header of the ListView.

```
private void ListView_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DependencyObject obj = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;

    while (obj != null && obj != myListView)
    {
        if (obj.GetType() == typeof(ListViewItem))
        {
            // Do something here
            MessageBox.Show("A ListViewItem was double clicked!");

            break;
        }
        obj = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work any more in .net 4.5. MouseButtonEventArgs doesn't have a (original) source.

Comment: @Harmen any solution in ***Net 4.5*** ?

Comment: Here's a solution based on events of the ListViewItem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728205/wpf-listview-attaching-a-double-click-on-an-item-event

Answer (score 64):

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="listViewItem_MouseDoubleClick" />
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

The only difficulty then is if you are interested in the underlying object the listviewitem maps to e.g.

```
private void listViewItem_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem item = sender as ListViewItem;
    object obj = item.Content;
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me on .NET 3.5 (VS 2008).  However, PreviewMouseDoubleClick worked.  Has something to do with event bubbling.

Comment: This does work for me in .net 3.5, however if you are having issues with the event bubbling up you could add e.Handled = true; to prevent it from going further than this method.

Comment: Works perfectly in .NET 4.5 and 4.6.

Answer (score 10):

Use the `ListView.HitTest` method

```
    private void listView_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var senderList  = (ListView) sender;
        var clickedItem = senderList.HitTest(e.Location).Item;
        if (clickedItem != null)
        {
            //do something
        }            
    }
```

Or the old way

```
    private void listView_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var senderList  = (ListView) sender;                        
        if (senderList.SelectedItems.Count == 1 && IsInBound(e.Location, senderList.SelectedItems[0].Bounds))
        {
            //Do something
        }
    }

    public  bool IsInBound(Point location, Rectangle bound)
    {
        return (bound.Y <= location.Y && 
                bound.Y + bound.Height >= location.Y &&
                bound.X <= location.X && 
                bound.X + bound.Width >= location.X);
    }
```

Comment: I don't see e.Location as a member in the MSDN or with my compiler.

Answer (score 7):

```
    private void positionsListView_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (positionsListView.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
        {
            ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection items = positionsListView.SelectedItems;

            ListViewItem lvItem = items[0];
            string what = lvItem.Text;

        }
    }
```

Comment: `ListViewItem lvItem = positionsListView.SelectedItems[0];` is neater

Answer (score 6):

I don't yet have a large enough reputation score to add a comment where it would be most helpful, but this is in relation to those asking about a .Net 4.5 solution.

You can use the mouse X and Y co-ordinates and the ListView method GetItemAt to find the item which has been clicked on.

```
private void ListView_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem item = myListView.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y)
    // Do something here
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I needed that as well. I found that on msdn:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.activation.aspx
I think this delegate is for that.

Comment: That's for the ListView control in Windows Forms. The WPF ListView control is in System.Windows.Controls.

Answer (score 4):

for me, I do double click of ListView in this code section .

```
    this.listView.Activation = ItemActivation.TwoClick;

    this.listView.ItemActivate += ListView1_ItemActivate;
```

[ItemActivate specify how user activate with items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/librarysystem.windows.forms.itemactivation%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

When user do double click, ListView1_ItemActivate will be trigger.
Property of ListView ItemActivate refers to access the collection of items selected.

```
    private void ListView1_ItemActivate(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (ListViewItem item in listView.SelectedItems)
           //do something

    }
```

it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I found this on Microsoft Dev Center. It works correctly and ignores double-clicking in wrong places. As you see, the point is that an item gets selected before double-click event is triggered.

```
private void listView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // user clicked an item of listview control
    if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
    {
        //do what you need to do here            
    }
}
```

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/588b1053-8a8f-44ab-8b44-2e42062fb663

Comment: This does not ignore double clicking in the wrong places in .net 4.5 or higher.  If you select an item and double click somewhere else, you take action on the selected item with this code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to get the selected object and object matching code for the double clicked listview item in a WPF listview:

```
/// <summary>
/// Get the object from the selected listview item.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="LV"></param>
/// <param name="originalSource"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private object GetListViewItemObject(ListView LV, object originalSource)
{
    DependencyObject dep = (DependencyObject)originalSource;
    while ((dep != null) && !(dep.GetType() == typeof(ListViewItem)))
    {
        dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
    }
    if (dep == null)
        return null;
    object obj = (Object)LV.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer(dep);
    return obj;
}

private void lvFiles_PreviewMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    object obj = GetListViewItemObject(lvFiles, e.OriginalSource);
    if (obj.GetType() == typeof(MyObject))
    {
        MyObject MyObject = (MyObject)obj;
        // Add the rest of your logic here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the ListView first, and then get the Selected ListViewItem.
I have an example for ListBox, but ListView should be similar.

```
private void listBox_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox box = sender as ListBox;
        if (box == null) {
            return;
        }
        MyInfo info = box.SelectedItem as MyInfo;
        if (info == null)
            return;
        /* your code here */
        }
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the ListBox DoubleClick event get the selecteditem(s) member of the listbox, and there you are.

```
void ListBox1DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("SelectedItem:\n{0}",listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()));
    }
```

Comment: If I use the ListBox double click event I can double click anywhere on the listview and if any item selected it will get. I dont need it. I need the clicked item only on when it was doubleclicked.

Comment: This doesn't work, because you'll catch double clicks on the scroll bar or other awkward places

Answer (score 0):

Either use the MouseDoubleClick event, and also, all the MouseClick events have a click count in the eventargs variable 'e'. So if e.ClickCount == 2, then doubleclicked.

Answer (score 0):

It's annoying, but the best way to do it is something like:

```
<DataTemplate Name="MyCoolDataTemplate">
    <Grid Loaded="HookLVIClicked" Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}}">
        <!-- your code here -->
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Then in the code:

```
public void HookLVIClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    var fe = (FrameworkElement)sender;
    var lvi = (ListViewItem)fe.Tag;
    lvi.MouseDoubleClick += MyMouseDoubleClickHandler;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Was having a similar issue with a ListBox wanting to open a window (Different View) with the SelectedItem as the context (in my case, so I can edit it).

The three options I've found are: 1. Code Behind 2. Using Attached Behaviors 3. Using Blend's i:Interaction and EventToCommand using MVVM-Light.

I went with the 3rd option, and it looks something along these lines:

```
<ListBox x:Name="You_Need_This_Name"  
ItemsSource="{Binding Your_Collection_Name_Here}"
SelectedItem="{Binding Your_Property_Name_Here, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
... rest of your needed stuff here ...
>
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
<i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
    <Command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Your_Command_Name_Here}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=You_Need_This_Name,Path=SelectedItem}"     />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

That's about it ... when you double click on the item you want, your method on the ViewModel will be called with the SelectedItem as parameter, and you can do whatever you want there :)

Answer (score 0):

The sender is of type ListView not ListViewItem.

```
    private void listViewTriggers_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ListView triggerView = sender as ListView;
        if (triggerView != null)
        {
            btnEditTrigger_Click(null, null);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

i see this subject is high on google, there is my simple and working sample :)

XAML:

```
    <ListView Name="MainTCList" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MinHeight="440" Height="Auto" Margin="10,10,5.115,4" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="500" Width="Auto" Grid.Column="0" MouseDoubleClick="MainTCList_MouseDoubleClick" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="UserTID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding UserTID}" Width="80"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Title" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Title}" Width="410" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

C#

```
    private void MainTCList_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
            TC item = (TC)MainTCList.Items.CurrentItem;
            Wyswietlacz.Content = item.UserTID;  
    }
```

Wyswietlacz is a test Label to see item content :) I add here in this last line a method to Load Page with data from item.