# How do I add a MouseDoubleClick event handler on a ListBox using the Visual Studio Design view?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, events, properties, mouseevent

I wanted to add a DoubleClick handler to an item in a ListBox (assume it is called `ListBox`), but I could not get it to appear using the Designer view.
I.E., double-clicking on the ListBox, I would only ever get `ListBox_SelectedIndexChanged` handlers wired up for me. (My list-box items are programmatically assigned, so there were no items in the Design view to click on -- is that an issue?)

I did work around this by coding up the handler myself (based on [C# Listbox Item Double Click Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454423/c-sharp-listbox-item-double-click-event)) but that took further research, since I had no idea that instead of looking for a `MouseEventHandler` in System, I had to drill down to `System.Windows.Forms.`. How annoying.

I.E., `this.ListBox.MouseDoubleClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.ListBox_MouseDoubleClick);`

So, is it possible to auto-generate a MouseDoubleClick event in the Design view?
Or do they have to be wired up by hand?

Not that I'm lazy, or anything. Other than using Visual Studio, I mean......

Comment: How about the Events view in the Properties tool window (a yellow lightning icon)? You can doubleclick an empty field next to the event name, and the event handler will be auto-generated for you. (If you were not aware of this approach, I can repost it as an answer)

Comment: I was not aware of this approach. Please repost it as an answer. doh!

Comment: Benefit of hindsight, why would I think that System.Windows.Forms would not have been the repository of methods for Windows Forms events?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Events view in the `Properties` tool window to generate a handler for almost every event (some generic event handlers are not supported, as I remember). To auto-generate an event handler, double-click the empty field next to the event name.

For your case with ListBox.MouseDoubleClick, here's how to do it:

[image: Using Events view to generate event handlers]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! After all these years, I think I need to hit up a "Visual Studio for Dummies" book, and look at all of the pictures VERY. CAREFULLY.

Comment: Yeah, I had exactly the same feeling when I discovered the Document Outline window after years of arranging containers/subcontainers using the mouse on the design surface :)