# how to typecast System.Windows.Controls to System.Windows.Forms wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to TypeCast `Windows.Controls` to `Windows.Form` but getting Null.

```
private void treeView_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{       
  var tv = sender as System.Windows.Forms.TreeView;
}
```

can I TypeCast `System.Windows.Controls` to `System.Windows.Forms` if yes then how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to MSDN

**windows.controls**- The System.Windows namespaces contain types **used in Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) applications**, including animation clients, user interface controls, data binding, and type conversion. System.Windows.Forms and its child namespaces are used for developing Windows Forms applications.

**System.Windows.Forms** - The System.Windows.Forms namespace **contains classes for creating Windows-based applications** that take full advantage of the rich user interface features available in the Microsoft Windows operating system.

So what you actually want is not possible at all.