# How to Handle SelectedIndex and Double Click event for ListBox in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, listbox, vb6-migration

I have a functionality regarding the **double click** of ListBox which already has **SelectedIndexChanged** event.The same events in vb6 works fine,but when it comes to single click the SelectedIndexChanged Event is firing always when I click for Double Click also.

I have tried to use timer and prevent the SelectedIndexChanged event,but no use always firing the SelectedIndexChanged event.

The event sequence in Vb is different when compared to VB.NET.

Comment: in what control in VB.NET do you want to handle?

Comment: For ListBox only Am Handling .

Answer (score 2):

The ListBox have two Event to Handle the *Double Click*

1. DoubleClick Event
2. MouseDoubleClick Event

msdn: [Control.DoubleClick Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.doubleclick.aspx)

Example for DoubleClick Event with items: [C# Listbox Item Double Click Event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4454519/1080742)

Answer (score 0):

You can't have both MouseDoubleClick and SelectedIndexChanged. When SelectedIndexChanged is used it supersedes MouseDoubleClick. Try using one or the other.

To be more exact, when the control is empty then MouseDoubleClick is fired but as soon as an item is added then SelectedIndexChanged fires and not MouseDoubleClick.

Hope this helps.