# Editable WPF ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, .net-3.5

I'd like to make a `ListView` editable when the user double clicks on an item. I realize that there are many samples out there on the web, however, these are all based on the `IsSelected` property, and not on handling the double-click event.

Any ideas or pointers?

*UPDATE:*
So one other problem that I have is, how can I get to the controls in the data template for the `ListViewitem` in question? Where I'm getting lost is the point where I need to get to the controls, and either enable or disable the control, based on whether the item is being edited or not.

Currently, the `ListView` data template looks like this:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Width="180" Text="{Binding Path=Description}"
              Style="{StaticResource GridBlockStyle}" />
         <TextBox Width="180" Text="{Binding Path=Description}" 
              Style="{StaticResource GridEditStyle}" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

The styles being referenced look like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key="GridBlockStyle">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected,
             RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
             AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, 
             Converter={StaticResource boolToVis}, 
             ConverterParameter=False}" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}" x:Key="GridEditStyle">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
            AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}},
            Converter={StaticResource boolToVis},
            ConverterParameter=True}" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

The `BoolToVisibilityConverter` is the converter for the `IsSelected` property of the `ListViewItem`, which then determines the `Visibility` of the ListViewItem.

As you can see from the current XAML markup, the edit controls will activate (become visible) on item selection, not item double-click.

*UPDATE 2:*
All the suggestions so far bring me to only half the way of the solution. Does anyone have a workable solution for how to access the actual controls that I need to make visible/invisible? I will mark that answer as the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in a MVVM pattern you may want to look at AttachedProperties and behaviors rather than event handlers to avoid writing code in your code behind.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/AttachedBehaviors.aspx

http://blog.fossmo.net/post/How-to-create-an-attached-property-in-WPF-using-a-ComboBox.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx

Comment: +1 Good call on attached behaviors. Little bit of a learning curve, especially if you're not used to defining your own Dependency Properties, but having a set of LeftClick/RightClick/DoubleClick properties you can bind from any element to any ICommand you like is great. [Here's another link](http://paul-taylor.co.uk/blog/post/2011/03/06/Attached-behaviour-for-double-click.aspx) that might help you avoid some pitfalls.

Comment: @djacobson yes, true about the learning curve, but once you get it, that's just great :) And this is a must have for building clean WPF MVVM apps

Answer (score 1):

Pointers:

[WPF ListView: Attaching a double-click (on an item) event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728205/wpf-listview-attaching-a-double-click-on-an-item-event)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/3d0eaa54-09a9-4c51-8677-8e90577e7bac/

[Get the item doubleclick event of listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929179/get-the-item-doubleclick-event-of-listview)

http://kevin-berridge.blogspot.com/2008/06/wpf-listboxitem-double-click.html

For MVVM,

[Firing a double click event from a WPF ListView item using MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035023/firing-a-double-click-event-from-a-wpf-listview-item-using-mvvm)