# Getting user input from listview

Tags: wpf

I created a listview. I need to get the user's input from the Textbox inside the listview. When user click on submit button User input from listview are displayed in a MessageBox. How to get user input from textbox inside the listview

```
<ListView x:Name="lstvQualification"
            Height="96"
            Margin="10,6,14,0"
            VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="249" Header="Education">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBox x:Name="txtEducation"
                                        Width="247"
                                        Text="{Binding education}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Width="253" Header="College/Institution">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBox x:Name="txtCollege"
                                        Width="251"
                                        Text="{Binding college}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Width="88" Header="Mark(%)">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBox x:Name="txtMark"
                                        Width="86"
                                        Text="{Binding mark}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Width="88" Header="Add">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Button x:Name="btnAddQualification"
                                    Click="btnAddQualification_Click"
                                    Content="Add"
                                    Style="{StaticResource NewImg}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>

<Button Content="Submit" x:name="submit" />
```

Comment: You have a lot of unnecessary StackPanels. If you only have a single item in your DataTemplate you don't need to wrap a container around it. You can safely delete all of them. As a general style pointer, 'education', 'college' and 'mark' are all properties on the object being passed into the ListView. These should be Capitalised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be the example for change in your code to work fine:

```
<ListView x:Name="myListView" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myCollectionViewSource},XPath='Party',Mode=TwoWay}">

            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath='Contact'}" Header="Contact"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath='Qty'}" Header="Q"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath='Amount'}" Header="Amt"/>
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="tbTot" Header="Tot">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <DockPanel>
                                    <TextBox LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus" Width="100" Text="{Binding XPath='Text'}" />
                                </DockPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>    
        </ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You already use `{Binding ...}` everywhere in the cell templates, those bindings are TwoWay by default, so any user input would/should automatically be passed to underlying data objects. However, I don't see any binding on `ListView.ItemsSource` property, so most probably you forgot to prepare the dataobjects. Create a collection of dataitems, bind them to the ItemsSource, let the ListView display them and celltemplates with bindings should update the dataitems' properties with no extra work from your side. When `submit` is pressed, just check the collection of dataitems, all the data entered should be already there (assuming you made all models and bindings properly).

Comment: Gives one example plz

Comment: @ShahidNeermunda: [Sample code on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771277(v=vs.85).aspx) - see the "download sample" link. [Another info here on stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652527/editable-wpf-listview). [and yet another idea](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/atc_avalon_team/archive/2006/03/14/550934.aspx).. please just search for it, there are many other samples and ideas. It all depends on how you would like it to be done and behave.