# How to know if any items in listview has been double-clicked?

Tags: c#, winforms

How can i JUST find out if any item in my listview has been **double clicked ?** ( not just clicked/one click )

I dont need to raise an action ( I dont want to use list_view1_ mouse double clicked )

---

Well,in my form there is an update button,so if any item has been double clicked I want to let the user proceed to another form,otherwise a message comes up and remind him to doubleClick on either of them items in list view

EXAMPLE) 
in my button 3 when user clicks:

```
if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0 && **listView1_DoubleClicked**)
{
    Form3 f3 = new Form3(mod, indexAppChange);
}
else messagebox.show(" double click on an item");
```

Comment: What you trying do on double click.

Comment: what is the platform? asp.net? silverlight? wpf? winforms?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the item doubleclick event of listview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929179/get-the-item-doubleclick-event-of-listview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find out by using [MouseDoubleClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb961984.aspx) event.

```
    private void listView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

The above event will fire when any item in listview is double clicked....

Comment: no, I dont want do anything with listview1_mouseDoubleClick event.I need to check in another button if any item has been double clicked or not

Comment: put one flag in mousedoubleclick item and make the flog true only when an item is double clicked....

Comment: hooking a doubleclick event to all the items in the list seems more logical and easier/cleaner to implement. any reason to do this in another way?

Comment: @farzinparsa - use Sai's answer, just declare a private bool member variable called listView1_DoubleClicked and in the MouseDoubleClickevent set listView1_DoubleClicked = true. That way when users click the button you have a flag telling you if they did double click an item. Anyway +1 from me.

Comment: Thanks Sai and Jeremy.
The best thing is ( as you advised) to declare a flag.