# How I can set listener on double click for sub-item of ListView?

Tags: android, listview, listener

I can't find this listener. Does it exist?
For example, I set the listener for one click:

```
ListView listCategories = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listCategories);
ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, titleCategories);
listCategories.setAdapter(mAdapter);
// Set listener:
listCategories.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemClicked, int position, long id) {
    // cod...
    }
}
```

But what about a double click?

Comment: I'd recommend a long press over a double click. Take a look at `OnItemLongClickListener` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener.html

Comment: as said by Andrew please go through android developer page.

Comment: This means that this void does not exist. Hm, why not. May be in future...

Answer (score 0):

```
private void ListView_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DependencyObject obj = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;

    while (obj != null && obj != myListView)
    {
        if (obj.GetType() == typeof(ListViewItem))
        {
            // Do something here on double click
            MessageBox.Show("A ListViewItem was double clicked!");

            break;
        }
        obj = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(obj);
    }
}
```

Refernce :[Get the item doubleclick event of listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929179/get-the-item-doubleclick-event-of-listview)

Comment: I need a cod for android)